# Add Custom Checkout Field (user input) to Order Data and User Meta

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I made this code to give user the possibility to add more user data during the checkout field

(inspired by code posted here in Stackoverflow, however I can't find the source anymore)

PHP in functions.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes','checkout_sections');
function checkout_sections(){
    echo '<div>';      
        echo '<h3>'. __( 'Add New Member', 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="row" id="readroot">';
        echo '<label for="fullname[]">Name and Surname</label>';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
        echo '<div class="md-form form-sm new_row">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="fullname[]" id="newfullname" placeholder="Name and Surname" class="form-control" required>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<label for="ALIMCode[]">A.L.IM. Membership Code</label>';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
        echo '<div class="md-form form-sm new_row">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="ALIMCode[]" id="newalimcode" placeholder="A.L.IM. Membership Code" class="form-control" required>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
        echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
        echo '<a id="moreFields" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<div class="row" id="writeroot"></div>';
        echo '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger waves-effect waves-light pull-right" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode;"><br>';
}
```

Here's Javascript code to clone the section.
JS:

```
var counter = 0;

//document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;

window.onload = loadEventListener();

function loadEventListener() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('moreFields');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function moreFields() {
  counter++;
  var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = '';
  newFields.style.display = 'row';
  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
      newField[i].name = theName + counter;
  }
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
  setTimeout(function() {loadEventListener();})
}
//window.onload = moreFields;
```

Here's the result during the checkout phase:
[image]

**WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH**
I want to add this data in my backend when I see the order (woocommerce-order-data) and in the user meta data, here's the mockup in the picture below:
[image]

**WHAT I'M DOING RIGHT NOW TO STORE DATA IN THE USER META DATA**
Right now, when guests are making an order, the code in functions.php will make a new user and add all the custom fields in the user meta and order data.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
// create account when buy
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Get the user email from the order
    $order_email = $order->billing_email;

    // Check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
    $email = email_exists( $order_email );  
    $user = username_exists( $order_email );

    // If the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout (new user)
    if ( $user == false && $email == false ) {
        // Random password with 12 chars
        $random_password = wp_generate_password();
        
        // Firstname
        $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        
        // Lastname
        $last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();

        // Role
        $role = 'customer';   //'customer'

        // Company Name
        $companys = $order->get_billing_company();

        // payment method (luca)
        $paymentuser = $order->get_payment_method_title();
        
        // Username (luca)
        $usernames = $first_name.$last_name.$companys; 
        
        // Create new user with email as username, newly created password and userrole          
        $user_id = wp_insert_user(
            array(
                'user_email' => $order_email,  //$order_mail
                'user_login' => $usernames,
                'user_pass'  => $random_password,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name'  => $last_name,
                'role'       => $role,
            )
        );
        
        // Get all WooCommerce emails Objects from WC_Emails Object instance
        $emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

        // Send WooCommerce "Customer New Account" email notification with the password
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger( $user_id, $random_password, true );

        // (Optional) WC guest customer identification
        //update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

        //codice per recuperare url file upload

        //$codedocu = $order->review_order_before_submit_upload_distinta_di_pagamento;
        //$urldocu =  'https://alimdigital.org/?checkout_fields_get=';
        //$urldocufine = '&checkout_fields_nonce=318982cbce';
        //$codefinal = $urldocu.$codedocu.$urldocufine;


        //$codedocu2 = $order->review_order_before_submit_upload_documento_identita;
        //$codedocu3 = $order->review_order_before_submit_upload_selfie_con_documento_identita;
        //$codedocu4 = $order->review_order_before_submit_upload_visura_camerale;
        //$codedocu5 = $order->review_order_before_submit_upload_proposta_di_statuto;
        
        //$codefinales = $urldocu.$codedocu2.$urldocufine; 
        //$codeselfie = $urldocu.$codedocu3.$urldocufine;
        //$codevisura = $urldocu.$codedocu4.$urldocufine;
        //$codestatuto = $urldocu.$codedocu5.$urldocufine;

        // User's billing data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_tipologia_iscritto', $order->billing_tipologia_iscritto );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nazione_sede_alim_di_riferimento', $order->billing_nazione_sede_alim_di_riferimento );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_sede_alim_di_riferimento', $order->billing_sede_alim_di_riferimento );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_categoria_socio', $order->billing_categoria_socio);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->billing_address_1 );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->billing_address_2);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->billing_city );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->billing_company );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_ateco_codice_nace', $order->billing_codice_ateco_codice_nace );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->billing_country );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order->billing_email );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->billing_first_name );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->billing_last_name );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_data_di_nascita', $order->billing_data_di_nascita );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->billing_phone );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->billing_postcode );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->billing_state );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_tipologia_territoriale_di_sede_alim_richiesta', $order->billing_tipologia_territoriale_di_sede_alim_richiesta );
        
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nazione', $order->billing_nazione);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_provincia', $order->billing_provincia);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_citta', $order->billing_citta);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_indirizzo', $order->billing_indirizzo);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_cap', $order->billing_cap);

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nazione_di_rilascio', $order->billing_nazione_di_rilascio);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_ente_di_rilascio', $order->billing_ente_di_rilascio);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_numero_documento', $order->billing_numero_documento);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_data_rilascio_documento', $order->billing_data_rilascio_documento );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_data_scadenza_documento', $order->billing_data_scadenza_documento );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nome_cognome_presidente', $order->billing_nome_cognome_presidente );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_iscrizione_alim', $order->billing_codice_iscrizione_alim );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nome_cognome_vicepresidente', $order->billing_nome_cognome_vicepresidente );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_iscrizione_alim2', $order->billing_codice_iscrizione_alim2 );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nome_cognome_segretario', $order->billing_nome_cognome_segretario );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_iscrizione_alim22', $order->billing_codice_iscrizione_alim22 );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nome_cognome_tesoriere', $order->billing_nome_cognome_tesoriere );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_iscrizione_alim222', $order->billing_codice_iscrizione_alim22 );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_nome_cognome_consigliere', $order->billing_nome_cognome_consigliere );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_codice_iscrizione_alim2222', $order->billing_codice_iscrizione_alim2222 );

        

        // Link past orders to this newly created customer
        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
        
        // Auto login
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    }  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    // Determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    // Get the user email from the order
    $order_email = $order->billing_email;
    
    // Check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
    $email = email_exists( $order_email );  
    $user = username_exists( $order_email );

    // If the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout (new user)
    if ( $user == false && $email == false ) {
        // Link
        $link = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) );

        // Format
        $format_link = '<a href="' . $link . '">logged in</a>';

        // Append to orginal string
        $str .= sprintf( __( ' An account has been automatically created for you and you are now %s. You will receive an email about this.', 'woocommerce' ), $format_link ); 
    }       

    return $str;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'filter_woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
```

If I made a mistake in providing the infos, let me know! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue!

Here's what I've done

I made all the sections I needed not visible and with Javascript I made them appear by click. Every field completed is saved in the order data.
Here's the JS (first snippet) and php (second snippet) code:

```js
window.onload = loadEventListener();

function loadEventListener() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener2() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction2');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener3() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction3');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener4() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction4');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener5() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction5');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener6() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction6');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener7() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction7');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener8() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction8');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener9() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction9');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function loadEventListener10() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('myFunction10');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember3");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction4() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember4");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember5");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction6() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember6");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction7() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember7");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction8() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember8");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction9() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember9");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}

function myFunction10() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newmember10");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } endif
}
```

```html
//

add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'customise_checkout_field', 20, 1 );

function customise_checkout_field( $checkout ){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    echo '<a onclick="myFunction()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<div id="newmember" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( 'New Member', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '01_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '01_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('01_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '01_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '01_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('01_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '01_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '01_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('01_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction2()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember1 finish

    echo '<div id="newmember2" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '02_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '02_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('02_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '02_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '02_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('02_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '02_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '02_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('02_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction3()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember2 finish

    echo '<div id="newmember3" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '03_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '03_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('03_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '03_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '03_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('03_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '03_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '03_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('03_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction4()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember3 finish
    
    echo '<div id="newmember4" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '04_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '04_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('04_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '04_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '04_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('04_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '04_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '04_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('04_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction5()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember4 finish 
    
        echo '<div id="newmember5" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '05_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '05_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('05_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '05_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '05_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('05_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '05_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '05_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('05_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction6()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember5 finish
    
    echo '<div id="newmember6" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '06_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '06_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('06_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '06_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '06_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('06_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '06_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '06_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('06_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction7()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember6 finish
    
    echo '<div id="newmember7" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '07_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '07_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('07_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '07_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '07_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('07_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '07_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '07_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('07_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction8()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember7 finish

    echo '<div id="newmember8" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '08_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '08_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('08_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '08_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '08_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('08_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '08_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '08_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('08_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction9()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember8 finish

    echo '<div id="newmember9" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '09_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '09_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('09_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '09_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '09_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('09_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '09_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '09_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('09_new_code') );
    
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
    echo '<div class="md-form form-sm">';
    echo '<a onclick="myFunction10()" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Click to Add new A.L.IM. Member</a>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember9 finish

    echo '<div id="newmember10" style="display:none">  
    <h3>' . __( '', $domain ) . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( '10_new_role', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '10_new_role form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Role', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('10_new_role') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '10_new_fullname', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '10_new_fullname form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Name and Surname', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('10_new_fullname') );

    woocommerce_form_field( '10_new_code', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array( '10_new_code form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'A.L.IM. Membership Code', $domain ) ,
        
    ), $checkout->get_value('10_new_code') );
    
    
    echo '</div>'; // div newmember10 finish

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

     
endif;

}

// Save custom checkout fields in the order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_checkout_fields_in_order_meta_data', 20, 2 );
function custom_checkout_fields_in_order_meta_data( $order, $data ) {

    if ( isset($_POST['01_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['01_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '01_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['01_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['01_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['01_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '01_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['01_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['01_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['01_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '01_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['01_new_code']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['02_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['02_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '02_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['02_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['02_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['02_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '02_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['02_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['02_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['02_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '02_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['02_new_code']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['03_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['03_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '03_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['03_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['03_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['03_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '03_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['03_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['03_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['03_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '03_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['03_new_code']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['04_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['04_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '04_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['04_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['04_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['04_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '04_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['04_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['04_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['04_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '04_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['04_new_code']) );
    
    if ( isset($_POST['05_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['05_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '05_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['05_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['05_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['05_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '05_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['05_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['05_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['05_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '05_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['05_new_code']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['06_new_role_role']) && ! empty($_POST['06_new_role_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '06_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['06_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['06_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['06_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '06_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['06_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['06_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['06_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '06_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['06_new_code']) );

        if ( isset($_POST['07_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['07_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '07_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['07_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['07_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['07_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '07_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['07_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['07_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['07_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '07_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['07_new_code']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['08_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['08_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '08_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['08_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['08_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['08_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '08_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['08_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['08_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['08_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '08_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['08_new_code']) );

        if ( isset($_POST['09_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['09_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '09_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['09_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['09_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['09_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '09_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['09_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['09_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['09_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '09_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['09_new_code']) );

        if ( isset($_POST['10_new_role']) && ! empty($_POST['10_new_role']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '10_new_role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['10_new_role']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['10_new_fullname']) && ! empty($_POST['10_new_fullname']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '10_new_fullname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['10_new_fullname']) );

    if ( isset($_POST['10_new_code']) && ! empty($_POST['10_new_code']) )
        $order->update_meta_data( '10_new_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['10_new_code']) );  

}
```